# Unsupported Error was thrown while handling a gesture. Unsupported operation: indexed set || flutter error

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I am working on a list of chip widget where the parent widget is ListView builder.
When I click on any of the chip I got this error  **The following UnsupportedError was thrown while handling a gesture:
Unsupported operation: indexed set
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:**

*I am working on flutter web*

here is my code:-

```
                            ChipList(
                              style: TextStyle(color: primaryBlue),
                              shouldWrap: true,
                              listOfChipNames: _dogNames,
                              // extraOnToggle: (index) {
                              //   print(index);
                              // },                                  
                              borderRadiiList: const [5],
                              activeBgColorList: const [Colors.white],
                              inactiveBgColorList: const [Colors.white],
                              activeTextColorList: const [Colors.white],
                              
                              listOfChipIndicesCurrentlySeclected: const [
                                100
                              ],
                              inactiveBorderColorList: [primaryBlue],
                              activeBorderColorList: [primaryBlue],
                            ),
```

[image: This is my error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with `ChipList` but looking at the [documentation of it](https://pub.dev/packages/chip_list#-warning-) it says an important warning message

> ⚠ Warning !  The flutter_lints package might suggest that you make
> listOfChipIndicesCurrentlySeclected a constant.
>
> PLEASE DO NOT DO SO. The widget will not respond to user interaction,
> seemingly without any reason.
>
> That list will be updated as the user interacts with the widget. It is
> intended to be used in case you would like to incorporate the contents
> for any logic.

I don't know if it's related to your issue, but I recommend removing the `const` keyword that you have at your `listOfChipIndicesCurrentlySeclected`

Comment: good catch! Even before using the package I read this warning but didn't give much thought.

Comment: @ᴅᴇʙᴊᴇᴇᴛ yeah, in my opinion it's a kind of bad for the creator of that package to have it like this. I'm sure it could be solved in the package in some way. Also the fact that it is called `Seclected` instead of `Selected` is bad. But you can also see that the package only had releases 12 months ago so it doesn't seem to be in active development. It's always good to keep in mind that errors you're having could be because of errors in packages. Not all packages are free of bugs

Comment: yeah you're right I will use another package then
thanks for the deep info.